# Why is the same stock almost twice it’s value on a different exchange?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-exchanges, adr

I have noticed that the value of AstraZeneca stocks on the European Xetra exchange is almost twice the value of its New York Stock exchange? 
How can this be?

Comment: Did you take into account the difference  based on the value of the currency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AstraZeneca shares on NYSE are [ADRs](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adr.asp) with a [2:1 ratio](https://www.astrazeneca.com/investor-relations/astrazeneca-adr-programme.html) to the underlying primary listing on the London Stock Exchange.

The difference you see can be accounted for by the above ratio, currency conversion and some slippage given the two exchanges are open at different times.